# css path for a file not in the same folder as the file

Tags: css

I have the following folders **projectCss** and inside it i have the folder **languageReference**,**css** and **js**.Inside the **css** folder i have the file **style.css**.

Inside the **languageReference** i have the three folders namely **iframes**,**docs** and **cssFiles**.Inside the iframes folder,i have the folders **codeSamples** and **htmlFiles**.Inside the htmlFiles folder,i have a html file called **index.html**.

My project setup looks like this visually.

```
projectCss

  *css  - style.css
  *langugeReference
           *docs
           *cssFiles
           *iframes
               *codeSamples
               *htmlFiles
                     *index.html
```

I am trying to figure out how my path will look like but nothing works.Can i get the path without resulting to serving the page on a web server?.

Comment: To be clear, you want to link `style.css` to `index.html`?

Comment: What have you current got that isn't working

Comment: path to which file ? 'nothing works.' what did you try please ?

Comment: ../../../css/style.css, am i wrong?

Comment: @OJay i was having ../../css/style.css

Comment: One more ../, as suggested by the other answers i.e. ../../../css/style.css

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Charlie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474478/css-path-for-a-file-not-in-the-same-folder-as-the-file#comment-21900633) said in the comments, you need to go "up" three folders (`../../../`) then select the folder and file like so:

```
<link href="../../../css/style.css" ... />
```

Alternatively, you could go from the "root", assuming your layout is the root, the following would work too:

```
<link href="/css/style.css" ... />
```

Answer (score 2):

Use relative paths :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../css/style.css">
```